# How to schedule a random timing (every random minutes) event

Tags: java, android, random, timer, timertask

I'm developing an Android App, I'm trying to manage a Vibration event. 
I need to schedule it every random minutes when a switch is checked. I have been using this code:

```
int delay3 = (60 + new Random().nextInt(60)) * 1000;

timer3.schedule(timerTask3, 0, delay3);
```

but the timer doesn't change `delay3` until the switch is unchecked and checked again. Is there a way to schedule the event at random timing i.e. `delay3` should change every time the task is running without unchecking the switch?

Thank you.

Comment: share your code what have you written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schedule the task to run after a random delay once. Inside the task, after the desired process, reschedule it after a random delay.

Example:

```
Random random = new Random();
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(timer, random), random.nextInt(10000));
```

with:

```
private static class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private final Timer timer;
    private final Random random;

    public MyTimerTask(Timer timer, Random random) {
        this.timer = timer;
        this.random = random;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("TEST");
        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(timer, random), random.nextInt(10000));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. It works well. Can you help me with canceling the task?

Comment: There is one drawback of this approach, if one task failed, the subsequent task won't be scheduled

Comment: @yusong You can just put the reschedule at the top of the run method, if that's the behavior you want. But you'll need to add a minimum value of the time your task takes to avoid running multiple instance of the task at the same time.

Comment: @italianfranny (Sorry for being so late) You can use an AtomicBoolean that you give to the task and that your main thread changes later and depending on its value reschedule or not in the run() method. I think you also need the field storing the AtomicBoolean in the task to be "volatile" to make sure it works (because the value will be changed by another thread than the one reading it).

Comment: Hi Nyamiou, I think the good way to solve it to always schedule next task in finally block, then even if task failed, finally block will still be executed

Comment: @yusong Good idea, I didn't tough of that, this way you can keep the advantage of running your code first before rescheduling again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `postDelayed` method of the `android.os.Handler` class instead of 
`scheduleAtFixedRate` method of the `java.util.Timer` class.

Simply create an instance of `android.os.Handler` class and invoke the `postDelayed` method of the `android.os.Handler` instance instead of creating an instance of `java.util.Timer` class and invoke the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method of the `java.util.Timer` instance.

Note that you have to replace `TimerTask` interface by `Runnable` interface.

At the end of the `run` method of the `Runnable` instance (passed as first parameter to the `postDelayed` method of the `android.os.Handler` instance) invoke again with new random delay the `postDelayed` method of the same `android.os.Handler` instance with the **same** `Runnable` instance!

No need to create new instance of `TimerTask` and no need to create new instance of `Runnable`!

This is more efficient because less objects are allocated on the heap memory and thus the garbage collector is less busy at deallocating objects from the heap memory this way!

There is a demo I wrote myself using my idea:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import java.util.Random;

public class Demo
{
   private boolean postAgain;
   public void start()
   {
       postAgain = true;
       final Handler handler = new Handler();
       final Random random = new Random();
       final Runnable runnable = () ->
       { 
           log.d("Hello");
           if (postAgain)
           {
               handler.postDelayed(runnable,random.nextInt(10000));
           }
       };
       handler.postDelayed(runnable,random.nextInt(10000));
   }

   public void stop() { postAgain = false; }
```

Note that the above code makes use of Java 8 lambda expression.
In Java 7 and below you can create an instance of `Runnable` interface that implements the `run` method without defining a new named class that implements 
the `Runnable` interface.

Also note that all the locals of the `start` method must be all `final` in order to be able to use them in the lambda expression or in the `run` method of the `Runnable` instance.

Invoke the `start` method to repeatedly print "Hello" at random delays and invoke the `stop` method to stop this.

Note that the `stop` method only sets a `boolean` field from true to false to stop the cycle.